# Get href link of a card which does not have anchor tag for it and link is generated on click

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have this website

https://kw.com/agent/search/TX/Texas%20City/

for which there is no href/link present for the card but on click of the card the page containing details for the card is opened.

How can I get link for those cards to the page to which I am getting redirected?

For eg for the first card

[image]

I expected I would get the link

https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6863980660422574080-3

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\Tools\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"

s = Service(chrome_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
url = 'https://kw.com/agent/search/TX/Texas%20City/'
driver.get(url)
```

##### Card html

```
<div class="AgentCard">
   <div class="AgentCard__main">
      <div class="AgentCard__avatar Avatar" data-testid="avatar">
         <div class="Avatar__container Avatar__container--highlight Avatar__container--null">
            <div class="AvatarImage__bg" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://cflare.smarteragent.com/rest/Resizer?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.googleapis.com%2Fattachment-prod-e2ad%2F808407%2Fc6604l887phbane09mh0.png&amp;quality=0.8&amp;webp=true&amp;sig_id=69&quot;);"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="AgentCard__avatarOverlay"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="AgentCard__content">
         <div class="AgentCard__name AgentCard__row">Jessica Agrella</div>
         <div class="AgentCard__languages AgentCard__row">English</div>
         <div class="AgentCard__location AgentCard__row">Katy, TX</div>
         <div>
            <div class="AgentCard__text AgentCard__row">License #694496</div>
            <div class="AgentCard__text AgentCard__row">Keller Williams Signature</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _href link of a card which does not have anchor tag_: Can you update the question with an example from the website?

Comment: I already have an example

Comment: @undetectedSelenium can you tell me atleast how is it working exactly on that site, which js function is creating the actual link?

Comment: Yeah, I need to relook at the DOM for the JS

Answer (score 1):

The url for each card is being generated on the fly, by javascript (or at least I couldn't find it in DOM). There is a way to deobfuscate each and every script running on page and look for the logic of generating said url... but I refuse to do that, on principle. Instead I will use selenium only. What  follows is a hack (in the good sense of the word):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t



chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url='https://kw.com/agent/search/TX/Texas%20City'

counter = 0
browser.get(url)

t.sleep(3)


WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'AgentCard__name.AgentCard__row')))
print(browser.current_url)
agent_cards = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'AgentCard__name.AgentCard__row')
print(len(agent_cards))

for x in range(len(agent_cards)):
    current_card = agent_cards[counter]
    print(current_card.text)
    browser.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', current_card)
#     print('scrolled elem into view')
    t.sleep(3)
    browser.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, -100);')
#     print('scrolled page by 100px')
#     t.sleep(5)
#     t.sleep(5)
    current_card.click()
    print(browser.current_url)
    browser.back()
    counter = counter + 1
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'AgentCard__name.AgentCard__row')))
    agent_cards = browser.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'AgentCard__name.AgentCard__row')
```

This returns:

```
https://kw.com/agent/search/TX/Texas%20City
48
Jessica Agrella
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6863980660422574080-3
Rick Aguilar
https://kw.com/agent/UPA-6587385217807011841-2
[....]
```

Comment: "There is a way to deobfuscate each and every script running on page and look for the logic of generating said url." can you throw some light on it, I was trying something like this only

Comment: I appreciate `browser.back()` but this is a vanilla approach and obviously this is not hard to do, what I am interested in  is getting the url of the cards by staying on the same page

Comment: Nonetheless I appreciate your effort, upvoted the answer!

Comment: You are asking about reverse-engineering obfuscated JS, which can take a lot of man-hours, often fruitless. It's not a situation you want to find yourself into.

Comment: So if it's not hard, why did you ask?

Comment: I am looking for a way where we can figure out the url using the js calls and events